# MarkLogic - Transaction size in harmonize flow

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version : 9.0-6.2

We use -batch_size and -transaction_size in mlcp.

We are able to use -Pbatchsize in harmonize flow, but could not find an equivalent parameter for transaction size. When would harmonize flow apply commit? For every single write or is there a default transaction size? Can we over write the default transaction size?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The transaction_size and batch_size would be the same in DHF's harmonize flow.

There's a single write that takes place after the batch in the transaction has finished.

Comment: Could you share the parameter name (like -Pbatchsize for batch size)?

Comment: -PbatchSize=100, or whatnot. Located in documentation https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/refs/gradle-tasks/